# mysql query inserting null value in a field

Tags: php, mysql

im using php and mysql

php code:

```
foreach($form1 as $value)
{ 

    if($value!='')
    {   
        echo $query="insert into group_mapping('mid','gid','client_id') values('$value','".$_REQUEST['gid']."','".$_REQUEST['userid']."');";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

when I run the query manually it inserts right, but using php code value of 'client_id' going (NULL), mid and gid inserting correctly.

no mysql error, i have also tried echoing the query and its fine.

Comment: insert into group_mapping(`mid`,`client_id`,`gid`) values('184','12345','111');insert into group_mapping(`mid`,`client_id`,`gid`) values('182','12345','111');insert into group_mapping(`mid`,`client_id`,`gid`) values('183','12345','111');

Comment: when I directly hit these queries, it works fine.

Comment: You might want to consider binding the values instead of directly inserting them from the $_REQUEST, serious SQL Injection problem... Not really related to your question but I felt like I needed to point out what major risk you are taking with that approach.

Comment: @AnkitGautam i have inserting the query using backticks but they were removed by editor and put the grey background.

Comment: @Blizz thanx for the advice i was unaware it causes sql injection. thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding some debug info into your script for example:
Also you shouldn't have `echo` in the line: `echo $query="insert....`

```
<?
if($_REQUEST['gid']!=''&&$_REQUEST['userid']!='')
{
    foreach($form1 as $value)
    {
        if($value!=''))
        {
            $query="insert into group_mapping('mid','gid','client_id') values('$value','".$_REQUEST['gid']."','".$_REQUEST['userid']."');";
            if(mysql_query($query))
            {
                echo 'Query OK: '.$query.'<br>';
            }else{
                echo 'Query Problem: '.$query.'<br>';
                echo mysql_error().'<br>';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'Value is blank<br>';
        }
    }
}else{
    echo '$_REQUEST[gid] or $_REQUEST[userid] missing<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanx for the help: debug info:

Comment: Value is blank
Query Problem: insert into group_mapping('mid','gid','client_id') values('183','111','12345');
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''mid','gid','client_id') values('183','111','12345')' at line 1
Query Problem: insert into group_mapping('mid','gid','client_id') values('182','111','12345');
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''mid','gid','client_id') values('182','111','12345')' at line

Comment: and also firefox executing the query and adding null value for client_id, and chrome not even inserting  the record

and both showing the same output above.

Comment: Ah I see! You're using single quote for the field names and you need to use backticks (under the escape key)

Comment: thankyou very much, it was a stupid mistake. removed ' and added `  .Now all working fine